# WP7 - playing mediaelement after page is loaded

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, mediaelement

I have this `MediaElement` in my xaml page:

```
<MediaElement 
            x:Name="soundMenu" 
            Source="Sounds/menu.wav" 
            AutoPlay="False" MediaEnded="soundMenu_MediaEnded"/>
```

and I want it to play when page is loaded (like background music):

```
void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     soundMenu.Play()
}
```

It doesn't work. When I click on some button and try to play music it's working but this isn't. What's wrong with this? How can I play sound after page is loaded?

P.s.: I know I must check if user is playing something. I just for now want to solve this issue:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes some time for the MediaElement to initialize. I guess in your case you try to start playing before the sound file has been loaded. Set AutoPlay to true or call the Play method in MediaOpened event handler.

Comment: AutoPlay can't help me because I must ask user with MessageBox if he wants to play music. But MediaOpened helps me. Thank you.