# Sound won't play in user control but will in my main page - Windows Phone

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have a .wav file sound effect in my app. For some reason it plays correctly in one place (a normal phone page), but when used elsewhere (within a usercontrol) it doesn't play (although I am using the same code and the code *is* executing).

And oddly (at least to me :) ) if I put a breakpoint before the sound is to play, then click Continue the sound will actually play in the emulator, which makes me think I need to do something extra to get my usercontrol to play sound correctly (since the same code works elsewhere).

I set up my sound in XAML like this:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="StampSound"
             Source="/Sounds/stamp.wav"
             Volume="1"                          
             AutoPlay="False" />
```

I use the same code in the XAML page and my user control to set up the sound. Then when I want my sound to play I use the following:

```
  StampSound.Play()
```

This works correctly in my main page, but in my user control it does not make a sound (but the code is executing, and if I put a breakpoint in and then continue the sound WILL play).

So I think my code is OK, but perhaps I'm missing something in my user control. I try to play the sound in the UserControl_Loaded sub, where I also (successfully) implemented an animation to go with the audio (incidentally an identical animation to the one the coincides with the sound in my main page).

Is there some timing type issue I'm ignorant of here? I'd appreciate any help or ideas.

This is for Windows Phone 8 XAML + VB.net, but I can manage with C# code.

EDIT: FOUND THE ANSWER

OK, I found the answer as I was about to post this, but the answer was for a slightly different question, so I thought I'd answer this in case someone else comes across it.

(answer from [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335987/wp7-playing-mediaelement-after-page-is-loaded)

I was apparently trying to play the sound before it was loaded, so I just added a handler for when the sound finished loading and played the sound in there:

```
Private Sub StampSound2_MediaOpened(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles StampSound2.MediaOpened
    StampSound2.Play()
End Sub
```

This works for me as I need to play the sound ASAP (i.e. it should ALWAYS play as soon as the control is loaded).

Comment: Please answer your own question and mark it as answer so other users can find it more quickly.

Comment: No worries. I did try to do this but it wouldn't let me answer until the question had been up for 8 hours ('cos I'm a noob).

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the answer as I was about to post this, but the answer was for a slightly different question, so I thought I'd answer this in case someone else comes across it.

(answer from [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335987/wp7-playing-mediaelement-after-page-is-loaded)

I was apparently trying to play the sound before it was loaded, so I just added a handler for when the sound finished loading and played the sound in there:

```
Private Sub StampSound2_MediaOpened(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles StampSound2.MediaOpened
    StampSound2.Play()
End Sub
```

This works for me as I need to play the sound ASAP (i.e. it should ALWAYS play as soon as the control is loaded).